# How to use sweetalert2 preConfirm with httpRequest which needs to be subscribed to within Angular 9 component

Tags: angular9, sweetalert2

I have an Angular form component which sends a http request and subscribes to that request.  Now I'm trying to add a sweetalert2 feature to start a loader when the form is submitted (onSubmit()) and the http request is executed (with doSubmit()) and I'd like the sweetalert modal to change to a success or error message when http request returns a response which is subscribed to by the component (resulting in execution of onSuccess() or onError()).  For some reason, my swal.preConfirm doesn't change the sweetalert from the loader to a success or error message.  Can you please help?

```
protected doSubmit(): Observable<NewUser> {
  swal.queue([{
    title: 'Registration',
    text: 'Processing your information',
    onBeforeOpen: () => {
      swal.showLoading()
    },
    preConfirm: () => {
      return this.onSuccess()
      .then(() =>
        swal.insertQueueStep({
          title: 'Success'
        })
      )
      .catch(() =>
        swal.insertQueueStep({
          title: 'Error'
        })
      )
    }
  }])
  return this.httpService.callDatabase<NewUser>('post', '/api/users/register', this.value)
}

onSubmit() {
  if (this.form.valid) {
    this.doSubmit().subscribe(
      () => {
        this.error = null;
        this.onSuccess();
      },
      err => {
        this.error = err
        this.onError();
      },
      () => {
        this.submitted = false;
        this.completed = true;
      }
    )
  }
}

onSuccess(){
  return new Promise((resolve){
    resolve('success')
})

onError(){
  return new Promise((reject){
    reject('error')
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a bit of a make shift solution for this issue without using swal.preConfirm.  Hopefully, there is a more elegant solution to achieving the same.  For now, here's my solution:

```
  protected doSubmit(): Observable<NewUser> {
    this.invalidOnError = '';
    this.navigationExtras = { queryParams: this.asssignToNavExtras.assignToNavExtras({ username: this.username.value }) };

    swal.fire({
      title: 'Registration',
      text: 'Processing your information',
      onBeforeOpen: () => {
        swal.showLoading()
      }
    })
      .then
    return this.httpService.callDatabase<NewUser>('post', '/api/users/register', this.value)
  };


onSubmit() {
  if (this.form.valid) {
    this.doSubmit().subscribe(
      () => {
        this.error = null;
        this.onSuccess();
      },
      err => {
        this.error = err
        this.onError();
      },
      () => {
        this.submitted = false;
        this.completed = true;
      }
    )
  }
}


  protected onSuccess() {
    swal.fire({
      title: 'Registration Successful',
      text: 'Thank you',
      icon: 'success',
      confirmButtonText: 'OK',
      buttonsStyling: false,
      customClass: {
        confirmButton: 'btn'
      },
      timer: 10000,
    })
  }

  protected onError() {
    swal.fire({
      showConfirmButton: false,
      timer: 10,
      onAfterClose: () => {
        code for where to place focus after sweetalert is closed
      }
    })
  }
```